# What is the difference between SEI and WSDL

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

I am trying to learn webservices using j2ee. I am not able to completely understand the difference between a WSDL and a Service Endpoint Interface. What is the purpose of each and are both of these auto generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WSDL** is *super set* :
XML-based interface description language

**SEI** is *one of element in WSDL* : A collection of operation elements describing the logical interface of a service(defines the methods to be exposed as a Web service).

[image]
This [picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language#/media/File:WSDL_11vs20.png) tells relationship between SEI and WSDL.
bottom side red box in WSDL 2.0 (in the WSDL 1.x interface was called portType)

Reason to compile to class.
Java did not recognize XML file.
It needs to convert to Java class object by [Jaxb](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/) [unmarshaling](http://actimem.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/jaxb.png?x78177) (opposite direction called marshaling)

**References** :

[Web Services Description Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language)

[introduction-to-jaxb](http://actimem.com/java/introduction-to-jaxb/)

[Introducing WSDL Contracts](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.6/html-single/apache_cxf_development_guide/index#WSDLIntro)

Comment: Very Useful and precise explanation.